# Inserting vertical bars in ng-repeat in angular-js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I was trying to fetch values from an array variable using ng-repeat in unordered lists. Now the values are coming nicely and everything is working but i have put vertical bars after each to show sub-categories in my page.

To make it more clear say my content  is the javascript file is following:-

```
$scope.content=['about','projects','contact'];
```

Now I have following in my HTML code:-

```
          <ul>
              <li class="sub-categories" ng-repeat="name in content">
                         {{name}} |
              </li>

            </ul>
```

As you can see that I need a bar after the name so that output is following:-

```
about | projects | contact
```

But the output is coming this way

```
 about  | projects | contact |
```

So i wanted to remove that last bar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). I'll suggest to use `border-right` with overriding for last child.

Comment: This can be done using only CSS and `::after` selector

Comment: eh? `content = ["about","|","projects","|", "contact"]`

Comment: @unflores if i have huge data set do u really expect me to put so many vertical bars?

Comment: I suppose I was reading your question rather literally. For what it's worth, I'm a fan of @Tushar's answer.  I think this is a css problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.content=['about','projects','contact'];
  })
```

```css
li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
   <ul>
              <li class="sub-categories" ng-repeat="name in content track by $index">
                         {{name}} <span ng-show = "!$last">|</span>
              </li>

            </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `{{name}} |` TO:  `{{name}} <span ng-if="!$last">|</span>`